# <select> CSS and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am facing a problem with jQuery and css. I need to show a div with id login-alert whenever someone selects from a dropdown list of options. I tried this but it is not working. Could someone please help me with this. What am I missing here?

```
<script>
$('.menu option').each(function() {
        <?php if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?>
        $('#login-alert').css('display', 'block !important');

        <?php endif; ?>
    };
</script>
```

Comment: `.each()` just runs your function immediately once per option element found, it doesn't do anything in response to the user changing the selection. Try `.change()` to assign a change event handler. (And note that your php code will have run once before the browser even received the page.)

Comment: is_logged_in() ??? How are you determining is_logged_in?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for your `menu` class please set the `.change(function(){...})`

When you have to change any option in menu then function will calls

```
<script>
$('.menu').change(function() {
        <?php if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?>
        $('#login-alert').css('display', 'block !important');

        <?php endif; ?>
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, did I miss something?

Comment: as it $('.menu').change(function()...}

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is not that clear but by assuming that the menu will be selected when the user has clicked the option in it :-

```
<script>

$(".menu option").bind("click", function(event) {
        $("#login-alert").show();
};

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

replace `each` with `change`... That way your **login-alert** will be triggered everytime that select changes.